# kafka stream stateStore : Same key in different partitions

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, partition, changelog

I used the kafka stream state store to store data and found that the same key was sent to a different partition in the topic: xxx-stateStore-changelog. When I obtained this key from the state store, I did not get the last put value..

Why does a key exist in different partitions?

Attached screenshot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AD9IB.png)

When I tried to retrieve all stored content through StateStore.all().forEachRemaining（）, some keys were not taken to the latest value.